# Rails Devise two edit routes one with password and another without password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to allow Users to have two edit pages, one which is the default Devise page that requires a password and the other edit page which allows them to edit some parts of their profile without a password.

I have seen their guide pages like [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password) which allows them to edit their profile without providing a password. However I want to have both options available to the user instead of just one.

How would I go about doing this?

**My Attempt**

I have tried to create my own update route in the Users controller which will solve the problem but this creates a problem when a User resets their password as it gets routed to the User#update which will cause an error as there is no User available during the password reset in Devise.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:crop] #:edit , :update

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user

  end

  def update
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      authorize @user
      if @user.update(user_params)
        flash[:success] = "You have successfully updated your profile!"
        redirect_to user_path(@user)
      else
        render :edit
      end
  end
  def crop
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
  end
  def index

  end

    private
    def user_params
       params.require(:user).permit(:poster_image_crop_x, :poster_image_crop_y, :poster_image_crop_w, :poster_image_crop_h)
    end

end
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :users,only: [:show] do
    member do
      get :crop
    end
 end
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks",:registrations => :registrations,:passwords => "passwords" }
  as :user do
    get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "/register" => "devise/registrations#new"
    get "/edit" => "devise/registrations#edit"
    delete "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

The code by Devise is suggesting to create your own controller. They probably always require password to be passed if it comes from an action in the UsersController. So you should create a seperate controller, let's call it ProfilesController, this controller is like your normal controller although it does not update a Profile model, but the User model directly... nothing special actually, just check authorization and let the User update any field you'd like directly on the User mode, do not forget to authorize the fields you'd wish to let the user update:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

 def index
 end
 ....... more code

  def update
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      authorize @user
      if @user.update(user_params)
        flash[:success] = "You have successfully updated your profile!"
        redirect_to user_path(@user)
      else
        render :edit
      end
  end

  ....... more code

    private
    def user_params
       params.require(:user).permit(:poster_image_crop_x, :poster_image_crop_y, :poster_image_crop_w, :poster_image_crop_h)
    end
end
```

And add `resources :profiles` to your routes file.

Comment: I like this approach and have employed it in a system using a `permissions` controller whereby an admin user can edit the permissions of other users without being able to access their main edit form (which handles personal info such as email address and resetting passwords).